# Android/Eclipse : Dealing with images' size

Tags: android, eclipse, image

I am building an android application with eclipse and I'm struggling to master the image positioning in the screen. I have put an image in a relative layout, and I want the borders of the image to match perfectly the borders of the screen, but when I extend the image manually it never fits and even if I put padding :/
(see the right side is ok, but not the left, the problem is not even a problem about the dimensions of the screen)

Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Thanks but this would be OK if I wanted to position the image center, or left or right. Can't I give the exact positions? I would like to stretch the image too

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that, you need to take the dimensions of the screen using this code :

```
// pixels
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Then you need to set programmatically the dimensions of the picture using the width and height properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that your image to be the backgroung of the activity you can use the background property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootRL"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">
</RelativeLayout>
```

The "@drawable/your_image_name" is your image. The image should be the dimensions that google recomends for deferent sizes of screen.

Comment: No, it's not the background of the activity. (See the image with the plate and the red lines), I will use that with a on touch listener